# C# - System.Windows.Forms - A type load exception has occurred

Tags: c#, assemblies

Full Script (More details below)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BuildShare
{
    class BuildSaveHandler
    {
        public static void ExportSaveToFile(Build.BuildSave save)
        {
            SaveFileDialog SaveToFile = new SaveFileDialog();
            SaveToFile.FileName = save.saveName + ".txt";
            SaveToFile.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";
            SaveToFile.ShowDialog();

            if (SaveToFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(SaveToFile.OpenFile());
                writer.WriteLine(JsonUtility.ToJson(save));
                writer.Dispose();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run ExportSaveFile, I get "Could not load type 'ThreadContext' from assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'". I simply run it by calling ExportSaveFile(etc.). Might I be missing required assemblies? The folder I'm running the application from only has access to the System.Windows.Forms.dll + other required assemblies.

This is an individial C# project and is being compiled into a dll. It uses the 4.61 .Net Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `SaveFileDialog` (or any System.Windows.Forms dialogs) in Unity3D.

Instead, use [EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel.html).

Comment: This is something I have to do at runtime, would that be possible with EditorUtility?

Comment: @MaximillionBilliony No, I don't think so. In order to do it at runtime you need to build a custom UI scene with the appropriate input text boxes and tree view (if you want to graphically select folders). The problem is that Unity is multi-platform so it can't compile those namespaces. It uses Mono, not .NET.

Comment: I see thank you. I would have to clarify that this script is being compiled in Visual Studio, so it's using the .NET Framework. This is more of a mod to a game, hence why I need to do things at runtime.

Comment: @MaximillionBilliony I wouldn't be so sure about that. Unity uses Visual Studio as the editor, but it still compiles for mono.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I think I'll end up making some kind of custom UI.

Comment: @MaximillionBilliony: You can set the target Framework of any Visual Studio project in the Project options. And Mono is as valid a target as .NET Framework or .NET Core are. And mono should be the default target framework for a Unity Project. It is perhaps the most important part of the Project Template

Comment: @Christopher Since this is more of a "mod", the target framework is the .NET Framework. Judging from what you said, this probably isn't the issue.